# Python repr & passing class instances as params

Tags: python, dictionary, key, repr, keyerror

So I have a class that I've set something like

```
class Piece: 
    def __init__(): 
        self.txt = "\u2665"

    # some methods...
    # including a method validMovements(), which works properly, no errors here

    def __repr__():
        return self.txt
```

Now i proceed to doing the following code

```
class GameManagement: 
    # various methods, no errors here

    def calculatePossibleMoves() # this is called at the end of each turn, for the next turn, this is also calculated in the initialization function of the GameManagement class, the problem is not here
        self.possibleMoves = {}
        for piece in self.piecesDict:  # contains all pieces
            self.possibleMoves[piece] = piece.validMovements()
```

Then, in another class, I use this variable

```
# note that self.selection contains an instance of the Piece class object
# and self.game contaisn a GameManaement class object
l = self.game.possibleMoves[self.selection]
# i get my error here, it seems liek in the GameManagement class, the dict uses the calss instance as key, however her it uses __repr__ as the key, instead of the object
```

Is there anyway to fix this (read details in the comments)?

The traceback goes as follows:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Saume\Workspace\ChessUI\src\ui\gameboard.py", line 189, in select
    self.move(event) # call move
  File "C:\Users\Saume\Workspace\ChessUI\src\ui\gameboard.py", line 205, in move
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\Saume\Workspace\ChessUI\src\ui\gameboard.py", line 142, in draw
    self.createcanvas()
  File "C:\Users\Saume\Workspace\ChessUI\src\ui\gameboard.py", line 120, in createcanvas
    l = self.game.aJouer[self.selection]
KeyError: ♙
```

Note, some of my code in the traceback is in french, but it goes exactly how i put it up there.

```
def select(self, event):
        """Selectionne une piece"""
        if self.selection == None: # il n'y a pas de selection
            try: 
                # coordonnees
                x = event.x // self.size
                y = event.y // self.size
                # piece
                p = self.game.board.getPiece(y, x)
                if p != None: 
                    if p.color == (self.game.time + 1) % 2: # piece de couleur alliee au joueur actuel 
                        self.selection = p
                    else: # piece ennemie
                        raise err.InvalidSelection("La piece selectionnee n'est pas de votre couleur.")
                else: 
                    raise err.EmptySelection("Il n'y a aucune piece sur la case selectionnee.")

            except err.InvalidSelection as e: 
                self.errorLabel.config(text=e) # afficher le message d'erreur
            except err.EmptySelection as e: 
                self.errorLabel.config(text=e) # afficher le message d'erreur
        else: # il y a deja une piece selectionnee
            self.move(event) # call move
        self.draw()
```

Comment: what is the content of `self.selection`?

Comment: self.selection contains a Piece type object, updated the code to show u the selection function i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is pretty clear - `self.game.aJouer` does not include, as a key, the piece that is in `self.selection`.

note that you do not show any code that *guarantees* this.  in fact, you don't show any code that shows `aJouer` at all.

the `__repr__` result is *not* used as key.  you are being misled by the error message.  when python wants to display an instance (eg when it is reporting an error), it calls `__repr__`.  that is all that is happening there.  there is no confusion between `__repr__` and the actual instance.

in fact, what is used as a key is the value returned by `__hash__` (which works along with `__equals__` in the hash algorithm in `dict`).  but if you have not replaced that then the default version should work just fine.